# Requests with Jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Currently I'm trying to add on to the auto-complete module for jquery that is out there.  After i've auto-completed my text field, i tab to my next field (a drop down). When that drop down is focused, i want to check against my text field and populate the drop down with a specific list depending on what the text field has.

Is this something jquery can do? I know I can do this by appending a script tag, and passing values back with json, but wanted to know if I could do something similar to this with jquery.

Thanks in advance.. still discovering this wonderful framework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be no big deal - you read the contents of the text field using $.val() then do $.get(url) to your PHP code that builds an object/array that maybe includes a success/failure flag, and converts it to json ([json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) and simply echos that back.

something like:

```
val entry = $('#textfield').val();
$.get('http://yourserver/getvalues.php', { entry: entry }, function(result) {
   if (result.success) {
      var options = result.options;
      $('#select').empty();
      $.each(options, function(key, value) {
         $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo('#select');
      }
   }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have this nearly working. the only thing right now that isn't working is the appendTo section. I am working on that now :)

Thanks!